# metro application - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-touch, gui, touchscreen, tablet

I'm looking for a Metro interface or even better a Metro application which runs under Ubuntu 20.04. The application should work with the touch screen of the tablet PC. (It should work like the Windows 8/10 start screen.)

It should be possible to start an application by touching a "tile" e.g. Firefox. For easy operation the Metro application should run as kiosk software.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider looking into [Ubuntu Frame](https://snapcraft.io/ubuntu-frame).

This seems to be the supported and recommended way to turn graphic applications on your Ubuntu device (Ubuntu LTS or Ubuntu Core) into a display kiosk.

Look further under the sections [Run Ubuntu Frame in your Desktop Environment](https://mir-server.io/docs/run-ubuntu-frame-on-your-desktop) (for running on a standard Ubuntu install) or [Run Ubuntu Frame on your Device](https://mir-server.io/docs/run-ubuntu-frame-on-your-device) (for running on Ubuntu Core).